# After button click result is displayed in label few seconds in gridview using js/jquery.The gridview in contentpage of masterpage

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have a master page and add scriptmanager in that.The asd.master page is

```
    <body id="myPage" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="60">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#myPage">Logo</a>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#values">Values</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#about">About us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#contact">Contact us</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="my account.aspx"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" style="color:orange"></span> My Account</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="jumbotron text-center">
            <h2>
                <asp:Label ID="headinglbl" runat="server" CssClass="control-label" Text="Label"></asp:Label></h2>
            <asp:Label ID="usrvstlbl" runat="server" CssClass="control-label" Text="" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
        </div>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </form>
</body>
```

In that master page i have 4 content pages,These content pages have gridview and also updatepanels. One of the content page is....

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
<div class="container text-center">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">                
            <div class="well">         
                <p>

                </p>
            </div>               
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-7">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="panel panel-default text-left">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="col-sm-12" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="8">
                                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                                <Columns>
                                    <asp:TemplateField>
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <div class="form-group col-sm-offset-1">
                                                <asp:Label ID="namelbl" runat="server" CssClass="control-label" Text='<%# Eval("LoginUserName") %>'></asp:Label><br />
                                                <asp:Label ID="datelbl" runat="server" CssClass="control-label" Text='<%# Eval("Date", "{0:M-dd-yyyy}") %>'></asp:Label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class=" col-sm-offset-1">
                                                <asp:Label ID="bkmsglbl" runat="server" CssClass="control-label" Text='<%# Eval("BookInfo") %>'></asp:Label>
                                            </div>

                                            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                                                <ContentTemplate>
                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-8 form-group">
                                                            <asp:Label ID="avlbkserrlbl" runat="server" CssClass="control-label" Text="" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label><br />
                                                            <asp:Label ID="avlbkslbl" runat="server" CssClass="control-label" Text="comments:"></asp:Label>
                                                            <asp:TextBox ID="avlbkstxt" runat="server" CssClass="form-control txtbdrclr" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="2" ToolTip="about book" ValidationGroup="avlbksgrp"></asp:TextBox>
                                                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="avlbkstxt" ErrorMessage="*Fill this" ValidationGroup="avlbksgrp" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-11 form-group">
                                                            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CssClass="btn btnbtn btn-success" Text="Post" ValidationGroup="avlbksgrp" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ConversationId") %>' CommandName="avlconvrsinsrt" />
                                                        </div>                                                            
                                                    </div>

                                                </ContentTemplate>
                                            </asp:UpdatePanel>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                </Columns>

                                <EmptyDataTemplate>
                                    <div class="emptytemp">
                                        At present we don't have any result's from your request....
                                    </div>
                                </EmptyDataTemplate>
                                <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />

                            </asp:GridView>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 well">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
      function hideuseravl() {
      window.setTimeout(function () {
      var label = document.getElementById('<%= avlbkserrlbl.ClientID %>');
      if (label != null) {
      label.style.display = 'none';
      }
     }, 6000);
   }
</script>
</asp:Content>
```

Then I bind data to my gridview in asdf.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = dataaccesslayer.getallavlblbks();
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
}

protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
        if (e.CommandName == "avlconvrsinsrt")
        {
            string logid = Session["uid"].ToString();
            string loguname = Session["uname"].ToString();
            string converid = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
            int rowindx = ((GridViewRow)((Button)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer).RowIndex;
            string avlbkmsg = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowindx].FindControl("avlbkstxt")).Text;
            Label grderrlbl = (Label)GridView1.Rows[rowindx].FindControl("avlbkserrlbl");

            if (avlbkmsg == "")
            {
                grderrlbl.Text = "Please enter any text";
            }
            else
            {
                dataaccesslayer avlcomtinrtobj = new dataaccesslayer();
                avlcomtinrtobj.avlbkcommtinsrt(converid, logid, loguname, avlbkmsg);
                grderrlbl.Text = "Your commant successfully placed....";
                System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, typeof(Page), "Script", "hideuseravl();", true);
            }
        }
}

protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
        GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        GridView1.DataSource = dataaccesslayer.getallavlblbks();
        GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

In this code, when i click button in gridview after filling textbox if submission is success then display a message in labelid:"grderrlbl".I want to display this label only few seconds after that hide the labelid "grderrlbl".

I tried this but not working.

```
function hideuseravl() {

          window.setTimeout(function () {
          var label = document.getElementById('<%= avlbkserrlbl.ClientID %>');
          if (label != null) {
          label.style.display = 'none';
          }
         }, 6000);
        }
```

The textboxid "avlbkstxt" have a required field validator, When i click button without fill textbox this required field is display all textboxs in gridview.I want to display required field in particular row where i click button.

Comment: Use `RegisterStartupScript` instead of `RegisterClientScriptBlock`

Comment: Please give an example

Comment: Something like this. `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "myScript", "doSomething();", true);`

Comment: I tried this,it's not working..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is full working (simplified) example of what you want.

```
<%-- .aspx --%>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <div>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="CategoryID" DataSourceID="sqlCat" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CategoryName" SortExpression="CategoryName">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                            <ContentTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CategoryID") %>'></asp:Label>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ErrorMessage="required" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" runat="server" 
                ValidationGroup='<%#Eval("CategoryID","grp{0}") %>' />
                <%-- diff valGr for each row --%>
                                <asp:Button Text="send" runat="server" ValidationGroup='<%#Eval("CategoryID","grp{0}") %>' CommandName="sendMsg" />
                            </ContentTemplate>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlCat" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NWind %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [CategoryID], [CategoryName] FROM [Categories]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showMsg(elId) {
        var el = document.getElementById(elId);
        el.style.display = 'inline';
        setTimeout(function () {
            el.style.display = 'none';
        }, 6000);
    }
</script>
```

Code behind

```
//.cs
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "sendMsg")
    {
        //Find row in easy way
        GridViewRow row = ((Button)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
        Label lblErr = row.FindControl("Label2") as Label;
        TextBox txt = row.FindControl("TextBox1") as TextBox;
        if (txt.Text == "test")//put your logic instead
        {
            lblErr.Text = "OK";
        }
        else
        {
            lblErr.Text = "Must be \"test\"";
        }
        //register code (function) which will run after AJAX update
        //Note that label.id comes from here
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "myScript", "showMsg('" + lblErr.ClientID + "');", true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure you add parameter in your `function` definition. Make sure you copy/paste `RegisterStartupScript` call correctly.

Comment: Done........... it's work what i want.your great Alex Kudryashev.Thank You for  solving my question.

Comment: The **value** of `elId` is set in `.cs` code. Exactly `"showMsg('" + lblErr.ClientID + "');"`

Comment: yes i find it.It is my mistake sorry for that.now i am happy for this solution.

Comment: When my textbox is submitted "lblErr" label is displayed and hidden successfully.But the  label is displayed again when i click button outside the updatepanel.That will never hide. the code like this                                           </ContentTemplate>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>                                       <asp:Button ID="outsideupnl" runat="server" Text="goto" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

Comment: `setTimeout(function () {el.innerHTML='';
            el.style.display = 'none';
        }, 6000);` This will help.

Comment: I try this change in my script, it's not remove error.Please help me

Comment: Add `style="display:none"` to your `lblErr`.

Comment: I already tryed display:none and visible:false properties but no change in error

Comment: `<asp:Label ID="lblErr" runat="server" style="display:none" />`

Comment: <asp:Label ID="lblErr" runat="server" style="display:none" Text="" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>.  style ="display:none" is hide completely, never show when submit textbox.What can i do

Comment: It **is** shown. look at `function` definition in *my* example.